# Add text to Alternativa3d?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, 3d

I'm creating an app with Alternativa3d (8.17.0), and would like to add labels to some cubes.  But it doesn't seem like the Alternativa API provides a way to do it...

Now I know I can either:

- Add a TextField to the Flash display list in the normal manner
- Render the text as a bitmap beforehand and upload as a resource to the GPU
- Render the text to a bitmap at run time, and upload as a resource to the GPU

BUT I need the content to be added directly to the Alternativa cube (which precludes the first option) and the text is dynamic (i.e. not known at compile time - precludes the second) and the third just feels hacky.

Is there a clean way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want the text displayed you could do a number of different things..

You could use a Sprite3D and add the text rendered as a bitmap. You can place the sprite3d near the cube and it will always face the camera so as you move around the cubes they will appear in 3d space but facing you at all times.

Another option is to add it to the actual cube as suggested by danii using a movieclip. However the link to that MovieClipMaterial is no longer valid and is actually for a previous version of Alternativa not version 8. I have created my own movieclipmaterial for version 8 here ( http://davidejones.com/blog/1392-moviematerial-alternativa3d-8/ ) should you want to do that.

Lastly you could render the text to bitmap and merge this with the cubes bitmap so the text is layered on top and then set this material onto the cube.

Personallt i'd use the sprite3d method its alot easier and i think will give a better effect. Take a look at this example which uses the same effect ( http://gkb40.ur.ru/web/map40a3d.swf )

Answer (score 0):

Just put your TextField inside a MovieClip, and use the class [MovieClipMaterial](http://alternativaplatform.com/en/docs/client/alternativa/engine3d/materials/MovieClipMaterial.html) to set that MovieClip as a material for one of the sides of the cube.